# How to properly call a function using argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm having some problems understanding how to properly execute functions based on arguments using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) and Python 2.7. The script itself is for [Caesar's cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

```
import argparse

def encipher(s):
    pass

def decipher(s):
    pass

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="(de)cipher a string using Caesar's cipher")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-s', default=1, help='shift length')
    group.add_argument('-c', dest='action', action='store_const', const=encipher, help='encipher a string')
    group.add_argument('-d', dest='action', action='store_const', const=decipher, help='decipher a string')
    parser.add_argument('s', metavar='string', help='string to (de)cipher')

    # call function (action) with string here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Where usage is meant to be:

```
$ ./cipher.py -c "he had a strange car"
if ibe b tusbohf dbs
```

How do I properly send the given string to the proper function, i.e. `encipher(s)` with `-c` and `decipher(s)` with `-d`, or optionally with `-s` with a different shift?

I've seen some examples that indicate you could test the contents of the parser manually, but wouldn't that defeat some of the purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function will be in `action`, the string in `s`:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
args.action(args.s)
```

Note that the declaration of the `-s` argument conflicts with the numbered argument `s`. You will only see the latter. You should change one of the names—for example change the numbered one to `string`, so the short `-s` can stay as it is.

Comment: This looked horribly wrong at first glance, but then I saw that the OP actually set up his argument parser to work this way.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do it! 

@user2357112 would you advice me to set it up any other way? I believe it's working as intended.

Comment: @timss: Well, it'd probably be good to set your parser up so that it requires exactly one of `-c` or `-d` to be specified, but other than that and the `-s`/`s` conflict, it looks good.

Comment: @user2357112 `-c` and `-d` are correctly set up to be mutally exclusive in OP’s code. You can’t specify both, and you have to specify one for it to not fail.

Comment: Oh for - I need to go to bed. I completely missed the `add_mutually_exclusive_group` line.